# Extract value from Python data dictionary column

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a DF with a column that is a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [10,{'self': 'https://elia.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/customFieldOption/10200', 'value': 'IT-Sourced Changes 2022', 'id': '10200'},30]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Data'])
```

How do I create a new column that selects only one value e.g. 'IT-Sourced Changes 2022'?

Thank you!

Comment: `df['new_col'] = df['requirement_source'].str['value']`

Comment: Please, post [mre]. Also check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632). Don't post images of code, error, data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`df['new_col']= df['requirement_source'].str['value']`

Should get the job done

Comment: It works on my 'created' example but on my real data it gives me an error: 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'

Comment: are you concatenating multiple dataframes in your real data ? Basically you have duplicate index in your dataframe which gives this result.